# When should ReactJS components make AJAX calls to update state from props?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a React component that displays information about an entity. The id of the entity is passed in via a property. The component starts an AJAX call in "componentDidMount" to fetch the entity and updates state when the call completes/fails.

This works fine except that the component does not fetch new data when the entity id changes (via props).

I have tried starting a call in "componentWillReceiveProps" but at that stage the component still has is old properties set. I would have to pass nextProps to the AJAX call method and that doesn't seem right.

What is the best/cleanest way to have a component asynchronously update its state in response to a property change?

Comment: I think you picked the best moment. From the docs:

Use this (`componentWillReceiveProps`) as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before `render()` is called by updating the state using `this.setState()`. The old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling `this.setState()` within this function will not trigger an additional render.

On the other hand, if you want the component to be updated before the call, I think `componentDidUpdate ` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd suggest you consider centralizing your data handling so that it's easier to manage these types of flows.

Comment: Yep, I guess the father should perform the action that triggers the AJAX call in the store. Then pass the data received from the store to the children as props.

Comment: @Edo that will just push the same problem up to the father component

Comment: I think it is not the case, as you would have just one place (controller) rather than multiple ones that perform the action. Then the store, rather than the components, would perform the AJAX call (having all the ids) and could return all the data. Then passing the new data as props would trigger the render.

Comment: The thing is that I would rather the "father" component didn't have to know what to fetch for the child component. The use-case is a dashboard display showing different bits of data for the same entity, each coming from a different endpoint.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I have simplified things a lot to isolate the question. In our app the component doesn't actually make the AJAX call (API layer does that) and doesn't get the data directly (it comes from Baobab).

Comment: @Edo Making the AJAX call in "componentWillReceiveProps" using nextProps seems to be working well

Answer (score 9):

I'm new to react as well, so the Flux architecture is a bit intimidating to me. I'm doing it exactly as you said, using `componentWillMount` to load initial data via AJAX, and then `componentWillReceiveProps` with `nextProps` to load new data again if/when props change:

```
var Table = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { data: [] };
  },

  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.dataSource();
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    this.dataSource(nextProps);
  },

  dataSource: function(props){
    props = props || this.props;

    return $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/products?page=' + props.page + "&pageSize=" + props.pageSize
    }).done(function(result){
      this.setState({ data: result });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <Head />
        <Body data={this.state.data}/>
      </table>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: When you're avoiding going the flux route this is pretty much the pattern to use. One refactoring to consider to make clear separation between fetching the data and rendering it would be to make render() something completely oblivious like `return <TableView data={this.state.data}/>`

Comment: componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state synchronously in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

Comment: This answer is outdated since React v16.3.0 deprecated both lifecycle hooks: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes

Answer (score 0):

The hooks `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated since React v16.3.0 ([source](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes)).

AJAX request should be done at the `componentDidMount` hook when you need to load data inmediatelly after the component is first rendered ([source](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)). When you wish to refresh the data after some props changed, you must use the `componentDidUpdate` hook.

But you'll have to take hand of another three lifecycle hooks to avoid starting an infinite loop of requests/updates. Assuming you wish to update a posts list based on `props.category` changes:

- `state` should have two properties, `category` and `currentCategory`, set null on the component's constructor;
- `getDerivedStateFromProps` is needed to update `state.category` from the new `props.category`;
- `shouldComponentUpdate` is needed to compare both `state.category` and `state.currentCategory` to determine if the component should be updated;
- `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` is needed to determine if `componentDidUpdate` should make an AJAX request or to change the `state.currentCategory` value and finish the updating cycle.

Complete code would look like this ([source](https://gist.github.com/camilokawerin/402533b49369c738eb3c69a499688a48)):

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class Post extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      category: null,
      currentCategory: null
    };
   
   this._createMarkup = this._createMarkup.bind();
 }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.category !== state.category) {
      return {
        category: props.category
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._fetchData();
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.state.currentCategory !== nextState.category;
  }

  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    return prevState.currentCategory !== prevState.category;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, dataDidFetch) {
   // dataDidFetch is returned by getSnapshotBeforeUpdate
    if (dataDidFetch) {
      this.setState({
        currentCategory: this.state.category
      });
    } else {
      this._fetchData();
    }
  }

  _fetchData() {
    const category = this.state.category; 
    axios.get(`/some/api/endpoint?category=${category}`).then(posts => {
      this.setState({
        posts: posts.data
      });
    });
  }

  _createMarkup(html) {
    return { __html: html };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.state.posts.map(post => (
            <article className="post" key={post.id}>
              <h2>{post.title.rendered}</h2>
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this._createMarkup( post.content.rendered )} />
              <p className="post-link">
                <a href="{post.resource_link_url}">{post.resource_link_label}</a>
              </p>
            </article>        
          ))}
        </Fragment>
      );
  }
}

export default Post;
```

Comment: As stated in [React doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), you should not copy your prop `category` into your state.

Comment: To prevent an infinite loop all you need is to check that the previous value of `category` is different from the new one in `componentDidUpdate`. No need for any state (the component is fully controlled), and no need for any of the 3 life cycles you mentioned.